# Create "Visualize-Touch" Behavior with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior, interaction

I am trying to animate a circle to visualize touch on controls. I've already done this by wiring to `MouseUp` event inside my user controls.

The current method is like this:

1- I put this Canvas somewhere in my usercontrol XAML file.

```
<Viewbox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Stretch="Fill">
        <Canvas Opacity="0.1" Height="60" Width="250" ClipToBounds="True">

            <Ellipse x:Name="touchEllipse" Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=UserControl}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" ScaleX="0"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="_touchTrans"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
```

2- Then I listen to `MouseUp` event of `UserControl` and begin the following storyboard by C# code:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="touchStoryboard" FillBehavior="Stop" x:Name="touchStoryboard">
        <!-- some double animations...... -->
    </Storyboard>
```

The Problem is here:

I am trying to create a `Behavior` that can attach to any `FrameworkElement` and listen to its `MouseUp` event and do the same thing...

I have already made some progress (well... not so much :D ). here's my Behavior class... How can I overlay that `Viewbox` on `AssociatedObject` and call the same storyboard?

Or do you suggest another approach for this problem?

```
 public class ShowTouchBehaviour : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp += AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        FrameworkElement e = sender as FrameworkElement;

        if (!e.IsEnabled)
            return;

        // now what?
    }

}
```

Thank You In advance.

Comment: Since FrameworkElement cannot host another FrameworkElement to overlay, you need a layered layout using Grid and Canvas. Naturally it will be somewhat complicated and become different from what you may expect.

Comment: Yes... I tried this too and it works, but it's not maintainable and reusable enough. Thank you.